# Can't show last JSON item in C#

Tags: c#, json

I started learning json and I have a problem in my first simple app

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Name: {0} \nAge: {1}", name, age);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string JSONstring = File.ReadAllText("bob.json");
            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            person p1 = ser.Deserialize<person>(JSONstring);
            Console.WriteLine(p1);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

and my json file is

```
{
  "Name": "BOB",
  "Age": 55
}
```

why is it giving me Age : 0 in the output?

how can I fix this problem?
and is this better or downloading and using Json.NET is better ?
thank you

[image: an image that describe my problem]

Comment: Are you getting name properly?

Comment: yes and it shows the right name " BOB" but the age is : 0

Comment: it works fine without any issue

Comment: @A.Sharkh I tried to execute your code and I didn't notice that you have mentioned. The value of Age that I saw in the console was 55. Are you sure that the json file you used contains an object with age 55?

Comment: Yes, I edited the posts so there is an image right now

Comment: How certain are you that the file you're reading is the one you're editing? If you change the name to "Fred" and rerun the program, does that show the change?

Comment: Thanks for helping I was having 2 files one in the project file and the other one in debug and I was editing the wrong one

Answer (score 2):

Use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for serializing and deserializing JSON in C#. For example

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("Name: {0} \nAge: {1}", Name, Age);
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var json = @"{
            'Name': 'BOB',
            'Age': 55
        }";
        var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(person);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Name: BOB 
Age: 55
```

See on fiddle [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yzZMAb).

Comment: @A.Sharkh yes; much better and faster than the `JavaScriptSerializer`.